# How to copy files from a directory based on items in a list of filenames in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have created following function to copy files from the directory(livepromptDir) based on the item in the list(promptList). So far, it only copy the first item in the list to the destination directory. Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
def copyItemToPrompt():
    #This function will copy all of the appropriate Voice Prompt files from LivePrompts directory to promptDir based on promptList

    os.chdir(livepromptDir)
    try:
        for i in range(0,len(promptList)):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(livepromptDir), promptList[i]):
                shutil.copy(filename, promptDir)
            return

    except Exception as error:
        log(logFile, 'An error has occurred in the copyLiveToPrompt function: ' + str(error))
        raise
```

Comment: Shift your return one indent back

Answer (score 2):

You want to move the `return` outside of the `for` loop, otherwise your function returns after the first iteration.  Actually, you don't even need the return:

```
def copyItemToPrompt():
    """This function will copy all of the appropriate Voice Prompt files from LivePrompts directory to promptDir based on promptList"""

    os.chdir(livepromptDir)
    try:
        for i in range(0,len(promptList)):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(livepromptDir), promptList[i]):
                shutil.copy(filename, promptDir)

    except Exception as error:
        log(logFile, 'An error has occurred in the copyLiveToPrompt function: ' + str(error))
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rcriii mentioned, the return is what's short-circuiting your function.  I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish, but I think you just want to copy a list of files from one dir to another given a list of glob-patterns.

If that's the case, and given you have a dir like this:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── tmp3
└── b
```

This function should give you a bit cleaner way to do this (things like `for i in range...` generally aren't used like you have here.)  Also, changing dirs can sometimes give you problems in the future if you fail to change back.

```
import shutil
from itertools import chain
from os import path
from glob import glob

def copy_with_patterns(src, dest, patterns):
    # add src dir to given patterns
    patterns = (path.join(src, x) for x in patterns)

    # get filtered list of files
    files = set(chain.from_iterable(glob(x) for x in patterns))

    # copy files
    for filename in files:
        shutil.copy(filename, filename.replace(src, dest))
```

Invoking this function like this:

```
copy_with_patterns('a', 'b', ['file*'])
```

Will make your dir now look like this:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── tmp3
└── b
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.